How to solve three coupled differential equations in python using RK-4 and shooting method? or using solve_bvp?
I am trying to solve three coupled differential equations in Python. I am using RK-4 techniques with Shooting method. I am trying to plot the f and N functions.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

alpha = 0.1

def F(r, f, v, N, sig):
    g = np.sin(f)
    h = np.cos(f)
    i = np.sin(2 * f)


    dfdr = v
    dNdr = -(alpha*r**2 * N * v**2 *(r**2 + 2 * g**2)+alpha * g**2 * (g**2 +2* r**2) + r**2*(N-1))/r**3
    dsigdr = ( alpha * sig * v**2 * (r**2 + 2 * g**2)) / r
    
    f1= v*((2 * dsigdr * g**2)/(sig * r**2)+(2 * dNdr * g**2)/(N * r**2)+((dsigdr)/sig +dNdr / N + 2 / r))
    dvdr = -(f1 -i/(N * r**2)+(-(2 * g**3 * h)/(N * r**4)+(v**2 * i)/r**2)) / (1 + (2 * g**2) / r**2)
    
    return [dfdr, dNdr, dsigdr, dvdr]

def rk4(F, r_range, f0, v0, N0, s0, h):
    r_values = np.arange(r_range[0], r_range[1], h)
    f_values = np.linspace(f0, 0, len(r_values))
    v_values = np.linspace(v0, 0, len(r_values))
    N_values = np.linspace(N0, 1, len(r_values))
    S_values = np.linspace(s0, 1, len(r_values))

    for i in range(1, len(r_values)):
        r = r_values[i-1]
        f = f_values[i-1]
        v = v_values[i-1]
        N = N_values[i-1]
        sig = S_values[i-1]
    
        k1f, k1v, k1N, k1S = F(r, f, v, N, sig)
        k2f, k2v, k2N, k2S = F(r + 0.5*h, f + 0.5*k1f*h, v + 0.5*k1v*h, N + 0.5*k1N*h, sig +0.5*k1S*h)
        k3f, k3v, k3N, k3S = F(r + 0.5*h, f + 0.5*k2f*h, v + 0.5*k2v*h, N + 0.5*k2N*h, sig +0.5*k2S*h)
        k4f, k4v, k4N, k4S = F(r + h, f + k3f*h, v + k3v*h, N + k3N*h, sig + k3S*h)
    
        f_values[i] = f + ((k1f + 2*k2f + 2*k3f + k4f)*h) / 6
        v_values[i] = v + ((k1v + 2*k2v + 2*k3v + k4v)*h) / 6
        N_values[i] = N + ((k1N + 2*k2N + 2*k3N + k4N)*h) / 6
        S_values[i] = sig + ((k1S + 2*k2S + 2*k3S + k4S)*h)/ 6
    
    return r_values, f_values, v_values, N_values, S_values

rmin = 0.001
rmax = 4
r_range=[rmin, rmax]
h = 0.00001

def objective(u):

    v0, s0 = u
    r_values, f_values, v_values, N_values, S_values = rk4(F, r_range, np.pi, v0, 1, s0, h)
    y1 = f_values[-1]
    y2 = S_values[-1]
    print(f"Objective results: y1={y1}, y2={y2}")

    return [y1 , y2 - 1]

initial_guess=[-0.478, -1.216]
v1 = fsolve(objective, initial_guess, xtol=1e-8)
print("The initial values of v0 and sig0 given by fsolve:", v1[0], " and ", v1[1])

r_values,  f_values, v_values, N_values, S_values = rk4(F, [rmin, rmax], np.pi, v1[0], 1, v1[1], h)
y3 = f_values[-1]
y4 = S_values[-1]
print("The value of f and sig at outer boundary is:", y3, y4)

if np.abs(y3) < 1e-6 and 1<= y4 <1.1:
    print("Boundary condition f(rmax) = 0 is satisfied, and the value of f at outer boundar is:", y3)
    print("Boundary condition sig(rmax) = 0 is satisfied, and the value of sig at outer boundar is:", y4)
else:
    print("The solutions did not converge")

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 10))
plt.plot(r_values, f_values, label='f(r)')
plt.plot(r_values, N_values, label='N(r)')
plt.title(r"$\alpha=0.1$")
plt.xlabel('r')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()

But the nature of the plot is completely different from my expectations. The output is
Objective results: y1=0.000372840219254553, y2=1.0001907509516712
Objective results: y1=0.000372840219254553, y2=1.0001907509516712
Objective results: y1=0.000372840219254553, y2=1.0001907509516712
Objective results: y1=0.00037294172854991653, y2=1.0001906882951273
Objective results: y1=0.000372824083910513, y2=1.0001907727358128
Objective results: y1=1.8398001535383646e-07, y2=0.9999999172810013
Objective results: y1=1.1072732970996606e-11, y2=1.0000000000024691
Objective results: y1=2.1284157569008075e-12, y2=0.9999999999969905
Objective results: y1=1.1784771089214975e-13, y2=0.9999999999997673
The initial values of v0 and sig0 given by fsolve: -0.4780664768861783  and  -1.2166450055671914
The value of f and sig at the outer boundary is: 1.1784771089214975e-13 0.9999999999997673
The solutions did not converge

As you see the value of sig at the outer boundary is almost one (0.9999999999997673).

This is the nature of the plot as expected

This is the plot I am getting

These are the three coupled differential equations with boundary conditions

I forgot to mention an extra condition on function N, here an extra condition on function N is given


I also tried the above code with a smaller value of h (=0.000001) and different values of rmin, rmax, alpha and initial_guess but the result was the same.
I also tried to solve the problem using solve_bvp. Here is the code using solve_bvp
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


alpha = 0.1


def F(r, f):
    #f, v, N, sig = S
    g = np.sin(f[0])
    h = np.cos(f[0])
    i = np.sin(2 * f[0])
    
    #dfdr = v
    dNdr = -( alpha * r**2 * f[2] * f[1]**2 * (r**2 + 2* g**2) +  alpha * g**2 * (g**2 +2* r**2) + r**2 * (f[2] - 1)) / r**3
    dsigdr = ( alpha * f[3] * f[1]**2 * (r**2 + 2 * g**2)) / r
    ter1=((dsigdr) / f[3] + dNdr / f[2] + 2 / r  +(2 * dsigdr * g**2) / (f[3] * r**2) + (2 * dNdr* g**2) / (f[2] * r**2))
    dvdr = -((f[1] * ter1 - i / (f[2] * r**2)) + (-(2 * g**3 * h) / (f[2] * r**4) + (f[1]**2 * i) / r**2)) / (1 + (2 * g**2) / r**2)
    
    return np.vstack((f[1], dvdr, dNdr, dsigdr))


def bc(fa, fb):
    return np.array([fa[0]-np.pi, fb[0]-0, fa[2]-1, fb[3]-1])

rmin = 0.001
rmax = 5
x = np.linspace(rmin, rmax, 100000)


y=np.ones([4, x.size])
y[0, :] = np.linspace(np.pi, 0, x.size)
y[1, :] = np.linspace(-0.2, 0, x.size)

y[2, :] = np.linspace(1, 1, x.size)
y[3] = np.ones(x.size)  


sol = solve_bvp(F, bc, x, y, tol=1e-8, max_nodes=100000, verbose=2)

if sol.success:
    print("Solution converged")
else:
    print("Solution did not converge")
    print("Residuals:", sol.message)
    print("Residuals max:", np.max(sol.rms_residuals))


print(sol)
#Plot the solutions
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 10))
plt.plot(sol.x, sol.y[0], label='f(r)')
#plt.plot(sol.x, sol.y[1], label='V(r)')
plt.plot(sol.x, sol.y[2], label='N(r)')
plt.xlabel('r')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()

When I am using solve_bvp, I am getting the following error
Iteration    Max residual  Max BC residual  Total nodes    Nodes added  
       1          1.06e+00       3.41e-21        100000        (199998)    
Number of nodes is exceeded after iteration 1. 
Maximum relative residual: 1.06e+00 
Maximum boundary residual: 3.41e-21
Solution did not converge
Residuals: The maximum number of mesh nodes is exceeded.
Residuals max: 1.0570652692628755
       message: 'The maximum number of mesh nodes is exceeded.'
         niter: 1
             p: None
 rms_residuals: array([4.25858920e-01, 2.54417888e-01, 1.98041640e-01, ...,
       6.12622641e-05, 6.11022248e-05, 6.09430998e-05])
           sol: <scipy.interpolate._interpolate.PPoly object at 0x000001B21E651DF0>
        status: 1
       success: False

The plot using solve_bvp is better but the success status is false.
The nature of the plot using solve_bvp

If it's a boundary-value problem why don't you use solve_bvp?

Yes, it is a boundary value problem. I also tried to solve using solve_bvp but I am getting the following error:
Number of nodes is exceeded after iteration 1.
Maximum relative residual: 1.06e+00
Maximum boundary residual: 3.41e-21
Solution did not converge
message: 'The maximum number of mesh nodes is exceeded.'
niter: 1
p: None
success: False (as you can see success status is not true). In the post, I have now added the code using solve_bvp.

Your problem is that you have singular boundaries. The challenge is one of numerical analysis, to identify boundary conditions for a small positive and a finite boundary, with continuations that are good approximations of the exact solutions. Sometimes the brutal approach works, but more often than not it invites convergence problems for the numerical method. Thus your question is better suited to scicomp.SE and perhaps math.SE.

If you include your extra condition on N (item number 4) then you would appear to have too many boundary conditions.

@LutzLehmann Thank you. I will try the brutal approach and just now posted the questions at Scicomp.StackExchange

@lastchance  Thank you. The extra condition on N at the outer boundary (i.e. infinity) is not necessary, one can ignore that condition.

@Prosenjit Paul, a couple of suggestions. Firstly, you might be able to use a Taylor series expansion to move your initial point away from the apparent singularity r=0. Many of the "singularity" terms are actually of the ambiguous form 0/0 that can sometimes be dealt with by, for example, L'Hopital's rule. Secondly, careful rearrangement suggests that you can ALMOST remove a factor 1+2.sin^2(f)/r^2 from most of the equations. Perhaps this will give you a change of variables. Anyway, do you have a link to where this problem came from?

@lastchance What type of rearrangement or change of variables? This is the problem of self-gravitating skyrmions. Here is the link to the paper: 1. Name of paper: Gravitating skyrmions, author name: P. Bizon,  Link: [https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/037026939291069L]. 2. This is a review paper, see section 7.4, Name of paper: Gravitating Non-Abelian Solitons and Black Holes with Yang-Mills Fields, author name: Mikhail S. Volkov and Dmitri V. Gal’tsov,  Link: [https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0370157399000101]

@Prosenjit Paul, in your shooting method you have an error in the order of the derivatives that you return. return [dfdr, dNdr, dsigdr, dvdr] should be return [dfdr, dvdr, dNdr, dsigdr]. I know it will probably be an irritating suggestion, but are you absolutely sure (a) that your intended equations are the correct ones (you are using very different notation to the paper that you link) and (b) that you have coded them correctly (your derivative function is heavily over-bracketed).

I am referring to your "shooting" code.
You have a major numerical error in the derivative routine, where return [dfdr, dNdr, dsigdr, dvdr] is the wrong order. The return order should be
return [dfdr, dvdr, dNdr, dsigdr]

You have an error in your equation (1), where you are missing a factor of 2 multiplying sin(2f) in the second line. Referring to the second of the references that you quote, this comes from differentiating 2.sin^2(f), which gives 4.sin(f)cos(f).df/dr, or 2.sin(2f).df/dr.
Your whole derivative routine is difficult to align with the original equations, so I have taken the liberty of rewriting it below.
You have correctly moved the lower boundary away from r=0. However, you can use the Taylor-series/power-series expansion to improve the values at rmin in this case: f(rmin)=pi+(df/dr)*rmin.
I think that you should increase rmax (to 10, say), whilst with Runge-Kutta you can easily increase h by at least a factor of 10 to speed up results.
Complete code below. Note that I have reverted to a value alpha=0.04 so that you can compare directly with your expected graph. (I have also divided f by pi in the picture, as is done there.)
Final code:
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

alpha = 0.04

def F(r, f, v, N, sig):
    S = math.sin(f)
    S2 = math.sin(2 * f)

    dfdr = v
    dNdr = -alpha*N*(r**2+2*S**2)*v**2/r - alpha*S**2*(S**2+2*r**2)/r**3 - (N-1)/r
    dsigdr = alpha*sig*v**2*(r**2+2*S**2)/r
    dvdr = ( (dNdr/N + dsigdr/sig)*(1+2*S**2/r**2) + 2/r + 2*S2*v/r**2 ) * v -(S2/N/r**2)*(1+N*v**2+S**2/r**2)
    dvdr = -dvdr/(1+2*S**2/r**2)

    return [dfdr, dvdr, dNdr, dsigdr]

def rk4(F, r_range, f0, v0, N0, s0, h):
    r_values = np.arange(r_range[0], r_range[1], h)
    f_values = np.linspace(f0, 0, len(r_values))
    v_values = np.linspace(v0, 0, len(r_values))
    N_values = np.linspace(N0, 1, len(r_values))
    S_values = np.linspace(s0, 1, len(r_values))

    for i in range(1, len(r_values)):
        r = r_values[i-1]
        f = f_values[i-1]
        v = v_values[i-1]
        N = N_values[i-1]
        sig = S_values[i-1]
    
        k1f, k1v, k1N, k1S = F(r, f, v, N, sig)
        k2f, k2v, k2N, k2S = F(r + 0.5*h, f + 0.5*k1f*h, v + 0.5*k1v*h, N + 0.5*k1N*h, sig +0.5*k1S*h)
        k3f, k3v, k3N, k3S = F(r + 0.5*h, f + 0.5*k2f*h, v + 0.5*k2v*h, N + 0.5*k2N*h, sig +0.5*k2S*h)
        k4f, k4v, k4N, k4S = F(r + h, f + k3f*h, v + k3v*h, N + k3N*h, sig + k3S*h)
    
        f_values[i] = f + ((k1f + 2*k2f + 2*k3f + k4f)*h) / 6
        v_values[i] = v + ((k1v + 2*k2v + 2*k3v + k4v)*h) / 6
        N_values[i] = N + ((k1N + 2*k2N + 2*k3N + k4N)*h) / 6
        S_values[i] = sig + ((k1S + 2*k2S + 2*k3S + k4S)*h)/ 6
    
    return r_values, f_values, v_values, N_values, S_values

rmin = 0.0001
rmax = 10
r_range=[rmin, rmax]
h = 0.0001


def objective(u):
    v0, s0 = u
    r_values, f_values, v_values, N_values, S_values = rk4(F, r_range, np.pi + v0 * rmin, v0, 1, s0, h)
    y1 = f_values[-1]
    y2 = S_values[-1]
    print(f"Objective results: y1={y1}, y2={y2}")
    return [y1 , y2 - 1]


initial_guess=[-2.794, 0.471 ]
v1 = fsolve(objective, initial_guess, xtol=1e-8)
print("The initial values of v0 and sig0 given by fsolve:", v1[0], " and ", v1[1])

r_values,  f_values, v_values, N_values, S_values = rk4(F, [rmin, rmax], np.pi + v1[0] * rmin, v1[0], 1, v1[1], h)
y3 = f_values[-1]
y4 = S_values[-1]
print("The value of f and sig at outer boundary is:", y3, y4)

if abs(y3) + abs( y4 - 1 ) < 1e-6:
    print("Boundary condition f(rmax) = 0 is satisfied, and the value of f at outer boundary is:", y3)
    print("Boundary condition sig(rmax) = 0 is satisfied, and the value of sig at outer boundary is:", y4)
else:
    print("The solutions did not converge")

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(r_values, f_values/np.pi, label='f(r)/pi')
plt.plot(r_values, N_values, label='N(r)')
plt.title(r"$\alpha=0.04$")
plt.xlabel('r')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Output:

Objective results: y1=0.00019542960351076646, y2=0.9993130868376403
Objective results: y1=0.00019542960351076646, y2=0.9993130868376403
Objective results: y1=0.00019542960351076646, y2=0.9993130868376403
Objective results: y1=0.0001954504980834034, y2=0.9993130650610034
Objective results: y1=0.00019542960351076646, y2=0.9993131017285548
Objective results: y1=2.1493424939744863e-07, y2=1.000000127532956
Objective results: y1=5.273386299353826e-10, y2=1.0000000001353808
Objective results: y1=7.569440649813437e-13, y2=0.9999999999992873
The initial values of v0 and sig0 given by fsolve: -2.7943898358693358  and  0.47122759362590755
The value of f and sig at outer boundary is: 7.569440649813437e-13 0.9999999999992873
Boundary condition f(rmax) = 0 is satisfied, and the value of f at outer boundary is: 7.569440649813437e-13
Boundary condition sig(rmax) = 0 is satisfied, and the value of sig at outer boundary is: 0.9999999999992873


Thank you for your help and it works perfectly. I've marked your answer as accepted.

when I am trying to put alpha greater than 0.04, the nature of the f changes, I change the initial guess, rmin/rmax but nothing happens. I also solved the problem using solve_ivp and solve_bvp but the same things happened here also, within the range 0 to 0.04 everything works perfectly but when alpha is greater than 0.04 the nature of f functions changes. Within solve_ivp, I change the method(RK45, DOP853,Radau,BDF), t_span, rtol/atol but the same thing happens, i.e. for alpha greater than 0.04 nature of f change. Is the solution only possible with the alpha range from 0 to 0.04?

@Prosenjit Paul, I think that you need to check with the two references that you gave. I skim-read them whilst trying to solve your problem and they certainly talked about different behaviour (no solutions or multiple solutions) for different values of alpha (or kappa in the second paper).

Now I understand it fully, Thank you so much.
